# how to reload a python package and restore all initial settings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I'm using a function from a python package that changes class attributes of multiple classes. Therefore, when I run the function once it's fine, but when I run it twice I run into problems. As a work-around I decided to reload the python packages, but I don't know how to do it in a way that all changes to the package or package's classes attributes are restored to the initial values.
(I know this might look like duplication, but I really read multiple posts on stackoverflow and can't find a solution that works for me.)

This is a toy example, that uses widely known library, but hopefully it explains well what is the issue:

```
import pandas
```

let's say something is changing or adding an attribute

```
pandas.tmp = 1
```

from various stackover questions I understood that I should use `importlib.reload` (using py3.7):

```
import importlib as imp
imp.reload(pandas)
```

but `pandas` still has `tmp` and this still returns 1

```
pandas.tmp
```

I've also tried to use `del` with similar result

```
del pandas
import pandas
# still returns 1
pandas.tmp
```

I've even tried to use `del sys.modules["pandas"]` but it leads to various problems depending on the package (I don't understand them, so won't even try to explain) and it does not solve my problems anyway.

Comment: Reloading can be very tricky - see the list of caveats in the [importlib.reload docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).  I would be more inclined to review the use of the "function from a python package that changes class attributes of multiple classes".

Comment: @snakecharmerb - thanks, I was reading the docs, but I don't fully understand it and also I thought that it must be a way to do it (even if it's not `reload`), but just can't find it... 
I agree that ideally the functions does not change the attributes, I've already post an issue, but wanted to know what could be a work-around.